Constructing a quantum circuit for a "simultaneous four qubit rotational swap"
I am looking to construct a circuit that implements the following unitary matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 &\cos(\theta) & -i\cdot\sin(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -i\cdot\sin(\theta) &\cos(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cos(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 & -i\cdot\sin(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cos(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -i\cdot\sin(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cos(\theta) & 0 & 0 & -i\cdot\sin(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cos(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 & -i\cdot\sin(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -i\cdot\sin(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cos(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -i\cdot\sin(\theta) & 0 & 0 &\cos(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -i\cdot\sin(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cos(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -i\cdot\sin(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cos(\theta) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cos(\theta) & -i\cdot\sin(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -i\cdot\sin(\theta) &\cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So it is essentially two "simultaneous" rotational swaps, where both swaps are applied with the same angle.
Unfortunately it is not as simple as running two swaps in parallel ($C_1X_2, C_2RX_1, C_1X_2$), because the resulting transformation leaves residual amplutides for unwanted states. Both swaps would hence need to be somehow entangled.
How would I go about constructing such a circuit? Does something like this already exist?
I've already tried applying general methods, however, the resulting circuits were comically large. More precisely, I've tried the algorithm described in Nielsen&Chuang using Gray codes as well as letting Qiskit do all the work. I am otherwise not familiar with approaches that apply to 4-qubit gates.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Are you looking a gate that behaves as $U(\theta)|\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle  = \cos(\theta)|\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle + i\sin(\theta)|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle$ ?
The best way to achieve this is to assume it is action from the evolution of some hamiltonian $H$ where, $ U(\theta)=e^{iH\theta}$.
We would then have $$e^{iH\theta} |\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle =\cos(\theta)|\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle + i\sin(\theta)|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle.$$
Differentiating both sides by $\theta$ and then setting $\theta=0$ will yield $H |\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle  =|\phi\rangle|\psi\rangle$, so is the swap of all qubits simultaneously.
QPE and hamiltonian simuluation will then give you a method for applying $e^{i\text{SWAP}\theta}$
EDIT:
To avoid additional qubits for QPE we can instead seek a $W$, that diagonalizes SWAP and then perform $W D W^\dagger$, where $D$ is diagonal and its constructions consists of only phase gates. Such a $W$ can be defined as $W:|i\rangle |j\rangle \rightarrow |i\rangle |j\rangle  + (-1)^{f(i,j)}|j\rangle |i\rangle  $ where $f(i,j) = 0 \text{ if } i\leq j \text{ else } 1$ and $i,j \in\{0,1,2,3\}$.
Building such a $W$ is the next task!

Thanks for you suggestion! Before I go and construct a Hamiltonian - is this functionally identical to Mark Spinellis answer?

The circuit Mark linked is what I was imagining. replacing S with with Rz(theta) should be the case I had in mind for the more general rotated swap (maybe up to some factor).
If you want to avoid the extra ancilla, perhaps you can find a nice unitary that is change in basis from  the computational basis  to a basis of symmetric and antisymmetric states. Then the phase will be easy to implement and then you can jump back afterwards. GHZ  states of some flavour would be worth playing around with.

@TorbenPeter I've added into the answer a method that wont involve extra qubits but still not as constructive as I think you'd like...

Is $W$ a four-qubit gate acting on the two pairs?  Or is it a two-qubit gate acting only on each pair separately? (If the latter where is the entanglement amongst the pairs generated?)

Sorry I should have said. W acts on all 4 qubits.  i,j range from 0 to 3 so are 2 qubits each.

@Ethan Davies Thx for keeping at it! Constructing a circuit that implements such a W is something I tried before through trial&error, which proved to be difficult. But it is the approach that seemed most intuitive for me at the start. Do you know of any concrete methods or even just intuitions on how to go about that?

All of my ideas (so far) will probably need at least 1 ancilla which would defeat the point. We do have an explicit formula for W now so can run that into one of the gate decompositions functions but that doesn't feel like a win here.

@CraigGidney helped me with a very similar question here.  I was interested in a circuit for $\sqrt{\text{SWAP}\otimes\text{SWAP}}$ but I saw that $\sqrt{\text{SWAP}}\otimes\sqrt{\text{SWAP}}$ did not generate the kind of entanglement I was envisioning.  This is analogous to your statement that "the resulting transformation leaves residual amplitudes for unwanted states".
Craig's circuit used a single ancilla to do a phase estimation.  This ancilla controlled the SWAPs for the two pairs of qubits, and was rotated with a $S$ gate and subsequently uncomputed.  We only need a single ancilla qubit because SWAP$^2$=I.
Here is the circuit for the square-root of a pair of SWAPs.  The top qubit is where all the action happens:

I think you should be able to do something similar by using an ancilla to control the rotational swaps for both pairs of qubits, and subsequently uncomputing the ancilla. That is, starting with your $C_1X_2, C_2RX_1, C_1X_2$ circuit but controlled with one other ancilla which is subsequently uncomputed, although I haven't worked out the circuit yet.
I also think this is morally the same as @Ethan's answer.

Ancilla qubits are just a state of mind.
What I mean is that, without clarifying which gates are allowed in your generating set, any question along the lines of "What is a circuit that achieves this particular unitary" can always be answered with "Yes.  The circuit is a gate that achieves the unitary".
There probably should be a convention of generating gates that the community uses when the generating set isn't specified.  Reading between the lines of your question, you're probably wanting something like Clifford + (single-qubit) rotations?  Perhaps it's provable, in that case, that you'll need at least one ancilla to achieve your circuit.

I actually studied that thread! And it certainly helped; the rotation can be accomplished by using a parametrized Z gate in place of the S gate in the circuit you linked. However, having to use an ancilla kind of bugs me. My hope is that I won't have to do phase estimation.

I guess without any ancilla, you'd need to have an entangling gate between at least one qubit of one pair and at least one qubit of the other pair, in order to have the pairs entangled and avoid the unwanted amplitudes.  Maybe do your circuit on one pair, then the other, then one qubit of the first pair with one qubit of the second pair, then the other qubit of the first pair with the other qubit of the second pair... or something.

Yeah, I've played around with this for quite a while already. :D I figured I needed a more systematic approach once guessing the circuit proved to be very difficult. My gut tells me that I'll need a single C(C?)RX and several CX around that to build the desired entanglement, since I've managed to build something similar in the past. However, that was using the Gray code method as a baseline, which appears to be not very helpful in this case.

Hi Mark, concerning your edit: I think if no gate set is given, a universal set can be assumed - at least in my case. Though Qiskit managed to do so very inefficiently, it was able to construct a circuit from my matrix representation. Therefore it should in theory be possible to create such a circuit. For a lack of a better option I will probably go with ancillae for now. Maybe I'll come across something more elegant in the future.
